# Updating DataGridView Through a Button Click Event on a Seperate Form

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, datagridview

Basically I am using a LocalDB that has a DataGridView on the main form (Form1).  To add a new entry I've included a Button (New Entry) to Form1.  When the New Entry Button is clicked, a Seperate Form (New Entry Form) pops up, where you can input all of the information you want to include in the entry.   The New Entry Form has a Submit button which i want to use to Update the DataGridView on Form1 and close the New Entry Form.  I'm not sure how to do this.  I can't figure out how to make Form1 contain an Event Handler(to listen for Submit Button Click located on New Entry Form).  Any Ideas.  I've seen a couple answer to similar questions on here, but I'm not really following them, please answer as if you're talking to a complete beginner at using C# winforms.

Comment: Show the new Entry Form as a dialog and check the return code when the form closes to see if you need to reload your grid.

Comment: this is actually very simple in nature.. the initial thing that you will need to do is capture the actual row that you are on in the datagrid.. I am assuming that you have as a hidden field in the datagrid some sort of Key or Id this is how you would capture the value of the id then store it in a variable.. then when you populate the textboxes, you will need to create a DataSet or something capture / store the values of the data and insert them into the database based on the keyId of the row that you were updating

Comment: @jac Thanks! Such a simple solution, and worked perfectly